Extracting value from nested object
I'm attempting to extract a particular value from a nested JSON response in PowerShell.
I am performing a GET method on a REST endpoint and getting the following back.
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 2370,
      "customFields": [
        "@{id=60; caption=M\u0026S Agreement Status ; type=Text; entryMethod=List; numberOfDecimals=0; value=Active}",
        "@{id=68; caption=Maintenance Renewal Notes; type=Text; entryMethod=EntryField; numberOfDecimals=0}",
        "@{id=81; caption=Reseller; type=Text; entryMethod=List; numberOfDecimals=0}",
        "@{id=105; caption=Product Type; type=Text; entryMethod=List; numberOfDecimals=0; value=GoAnywhere}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1
}

I am unsure of how to extract the "value" field which contains "GoAnywhere" from the final nested string.
I have tried this.
$agreementsResponse | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object{$_.value} | Select customFields

and it is getting me a single string in an Object:
customFields                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
{@{id=60; caption=M&S Agreement Status ; type=Text; entryMethod=List; numberOfDecimals=0; value=Active}, @{id=68; caption=Maintenance Renewal Notes; type=Text; entryMethod=EntryField; numberOfDecimals=0}, @{id=8...


do the lines in customFields from your json example really look like "@{id=.... }" ?

Yep, but from what I can tell, they are just Strings.

That's a really odd response from an API. Those are "string" representations of powershell custom objects...

That comment doesn't surprise me, this output is from ConnectWise Manage which has quite a number of quirks in the way it works.

How are you determining the rest response is what you’ve shown? Is it literally the body text in the http response, or are you converting the output from Invoke-RestMethod back into json with ConvertTo-Json to see it on screen? The format suggests something is converting a structured object to json in Powershell 5.1 but because there’s a default max depth of 2 anything deeper is being “stringified” by Powershell rather than converted to deeply nested json. That could be the server so you already see it in the response you get back, or it could be somewhere in your code…

This is a really odd API response, what you have in the customFields Json array seem to be string representations of PowerShell's custom objects. I assume what you're looking to do is extract the line that has a value=GoAnywhere, perhaps a good approach can be to convert these strings into objects, then it will be easier to extract data from them. See ConvertFrom-StringData for details.
Using the Json sample from question the code would be:
$json = $agreementsResponse | ConvertFrom-Json
$result = $json.value.customFields | ForEach-Object {
    $hash = $_ -replace '^@\{|\}$' -replace '\s*;\s*', "`n" |
        ConvertFrom-StringData

    if ($hash.ContainsKey('value') -and $hash['value'] -eq 'GoAnywhere') {
        $hash
    }
}
$result

Then, in $result, for this specific example you'd get a single hashtable than you can easily manipulate / extract information from:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
id                             105
value                          GoAnywhere
entryMethod                    List
type                           Text
numberOfDecimals               0
caption                        Product Type

